# NGINX Ingress Controller Configuration In AKS (SSH/GIT)

Tags: git, ssh, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I want to allows SSH access(port 22) to my Kubernetes services from outside the Kubernetes cluster. because my deployed application contain git server.

Could you please suggest me a solution because it's blocking situation for me.

I was able to do clone/push using http/https, But it seems that SSH protocol is not covered by Ingress Controller .

Comment: A little look at the definition of ingress would be a good idea ;) https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress . And a look here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Answer (score 0):

nginx-ingress-controller supports this use-case.

As mentioned in the documentation for exposing tcp services(https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). A configmap needs to be created for this purpose.
eg.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-basic
data:
  22: "ssh-app-namespace/ssh-service:22"
```

Then add **--tcp-services-configmap=ingress-basic/tcp-services** to nginx-ingress-controller container command in the deployment manifest.

Configure containerPort 22 in deployment manifest(pod spec) of nginx-ingress-controller.

Check if the service and endpoint of ingress-nginx-controller is correctly configured for port 22.

**On the side of tcp-service that needs to be exposed:**

Make sure the containerPort is rightly configured in the ssh-service pod and its service.

I use service type of load-balancer for the ssh-service deployment to achieve this.

Haven't tried with ClusterIP, however can confirm it only after trying it out

It can also be used for exposing or accessing other tcp/udp services like database etc running inside a k8s cluster